# How to use Node.js in windows 8 javascript app

Tags: node.js, azure, windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services

I read both of these thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/1639e5e9-d334-4bc4-8636-aaac4de9d26b

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/8c9a840a-91a5-4d50-88fc-8ba346c8c387

Which make me confused!

what I want to do is create a Azure table storage in windows 8 app.

But by learn Mobile service I only find this sample:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Use-Table-Storage-in-0b6bcbc7/sourcecode?fileId=79395&pathId=418377534

It seems I can only CRUD storage tables with Mobile service with Node.js.

But I don't know how to create a table in that server script.

I want to use some thing like this:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/web-app-with-storage/

How can directly use this in windows 8 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only can use Node.js on the server side.
I use mobile service, Although I don't like to debug on server side.